# finger print sensor for project

Tags: programming

I am an engineering student and I am doing my minor project which uses finger print sensor and I am using R30x series. Can I work in the Ubuntu platform and work with the module that I have got. please give me the appropriate answer. I want to use QT or python to make a database to store the result of finger print sensor. Can we interface the finger print module in Ubuntu. If yes then what are the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Finger printer drivers as :

```
sudo apt-get install fprintd fprint-demo libfprint0
```